# Shift key in browser paste event not supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using chrome/jquery. When pressing CMD+SHIFT+V, the event says that shiftKey is undefined.

```
$('.pasteable').on('paste', function(event) {
    event.shiftKey; //undefined
});
```

Is it possible to support a "special paste" (CMD+SHIFT+V) in browsers in 2016?

EDIT: whatever, I did it by listening to key events

```
 var isShift = false;
 $('.pasteable').on('keydown', function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode === 86) { //V for paste
         if ((event.metaKey || event.ctrlKey) && event.shiftKey) {
             isShift = true;
         }
     }
 });

 $('.pasteable')'.on('keyup', function(event) {
     isShift = false;
 });

 $('.pasteable')'.on('paste', function(event) {
     if (isShift) {
        //works!
     }
 });
```

Comment: `paste` event isn't a keyboard event, it doesn't handle any key code

Comment: so I should listen to the keypresses, save some state and then use it in the paste event?

Comment: Yes. Do it on `keydown`, or `keyup` events.

Comment: But i'm really not sure what is your expected behaviour?! You want to detect if user pastes some value using shortcut keys or what? If so, why would you need it?

Comment: Special paste, lots of apps support CMD+V for one function and CMD+SHIFT+V for another

Comment: I'm also hitting a case where a jQuery event `type: "keydown"` has a `shiftKey: undefined`, and this with Chrome 61.